# Using buttons with graphics in Java applet

Tags: java, applet

I have an applet that draws a grid using drawLine() and then allows user to place and remove .png images by clicking on the grid. Now I want to add some interface buttons to the right of the drawing space, how can I do that? Currently a button refuses to move to the coordinates I want, and surely there is a proper way to do it?

```
package test2;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainClass extends Applet implements MouseListener{

    final int columnNumber = 10; //Number of columns
    final int rowNumber = 8; //Number of rows

    final int gridSize = 51;

    private URL base;

    //element images
    private Image whiteSquare, resistanceHor, resistanceVer;

    //creating a GridElement array
    GridElement[][] gridElement = new GridElement[columnNumber][rowNumber];

    public void init()  {

        setSize(columnNumber*gridSize + 100, rowNumber*gridSize);
        //Here I try to add a button
        Button resistanceButton = new Button("Button1");
        resistanceButton.setLocation(columnNumber*gridSize, 20);
        this.add(resistanceButton);

        try {
            base = getDocumentBase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        resistanceHor = getImage(base, "data/resistance_hor.png");
        resistanceVer = getImage(base, "data/resistance_ver.png");
        whiteSquare = getImage(base, "data/white_square.png");

        // Add the MouseListener to applet
        addMouseListener(this);

        for(int xcount=0; xcount<columnNumber;xcount++){

            for(int ycount=0; ycount<rowNumber;ycount++){
                //set top left corner  coordinates for all grid elements and declare them empty and non-vertical
                gridElement[xcount][ycount] = new GridElement(gridSize*xcount, gridSize*ycount,true,false);

            }
        }
    }

    public void update(Graphics g) {
        paint(g);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){

        //set grid color
        Color gridGrey = new Color(208,195,195);        
        g.setColor(gridGrey); 

        //draw grid
        for(int xcount=0; xcount<columnNumber;xcount++){

            g.drawLine(xcount*gridSize, 0, xcount*gridSize, rowNumber*gridSize);
        }

        for(int ycount=0; ycount<rowNumber;ycount++){

            g.drawLine(0, ycount*gridSize, columnNumber*gridSize, ycount*gridSize);
        }

        //draw png images in non-empty squares
        for(int xcount=0; xcount<columnNumber;xcount++){

            for(int ycount=0; ycount<rowNumber;ycount++){

                if(gridElement[xcount][ycount].isEmpty() == false){
                    g.drawImage(resistanceHor, gridElement[xcount][ycount].getxTopLeftCorner(), gridElement[xcount][ycount].getyTopLeftCorner(), this);
                }
                else{
                    g.setColor( getBackground() );
                    g.fillRect(gridElement[xcount][ycount].getxTopLeftCorner()+1, gridElement[xcount][ycount].getyTopLeftCorner()+1, gridSize-1, gridSize-1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent me) {

        int col = me.getX() / gridSize;   // Column where user clicked.
        int row = me.getY() / gridSize;   // Row where user clicked.

        //if a square is empty, make it not empty, if it is not empty, make it empty
        if(gridElement[col][row].isEmpty() == true){
            gridElement[col][row].setEmpty(false);
        }
        else{
            gridElement[col][row].setEmpty(true);
        }

        repaint();
    }   
    public void mousePressed (MouseEvent me) {}
    public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent me) {} 
    public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent me) {}
    public void mouseExited (MouseEvent me) {} 
}

package test2;

public class GridElement {

private int xTopLeftCorner;
private int yTopLeftCorner;

private boolean vertical;
private boolean empty;

private boolean isResistor;

GridElement(int xTopLeftCorner, int yTopLeftCorner,  boolean empty, boolean vertical){
    this.xTopLeftCorner = xTopLeftCorner;
    this.yTopLeftCorner = yTopLeftCorner;
    this.empty = empty;
    this.vertical = vertical;

}

public boolean isResistor() {
    return isResistor;
}

public void setResistor(boolean isResistor) {
    this.isResistor = isResistor;
}

public boolean isVertical() {
    return vertical;
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return empty;
}
public void setVertical(boolean vertical) {
    this.vertical = vertical;
}
public void setEmpty(boolean empty) {
    this.empty = empty;
}

public int getxTopLeftCorner() {
    return xTopLeftCorner;
}

public int getyTopLeftCorner() {
    return yTopLeftCorner;
}

public void setxTopLeftCorner(int xTopLeftCorner) {
    this.xTopLeftCorner = xTopLeftCorner;
}

public void setyTopLeftCorner(int yTopLeftCorner) {
    this.yTopLeftCorner = yTopLeftCorner;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You need to learn about layout managers.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Basically top-level containers like Applet,JApplet,Frame,JFrame,Dialog,JDialog,etc. have a default layout manager of [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html). When you `add(component)` to a container with a BorderLayout, the component gets added to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position. Not only that, but BorderLayout doesn't respect the preferred sizes of components, meaning that the component will stretch to fit the container. In your case, it will take up entire frame.

Solution.

- Don't paint on the applet component itself. Paint in a `Panel` instead. Add the panel to the applet container. (CENTER is ok)
- Create another `Panel` and add the button to *that* panel, then add the panel to `BorderLayout.LINE_END`, like `add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);`

---

Other important notes:

- Unless this is a class assignment and the professor explicitly said to use AWT component.. Don't. Use Swing component instead. Swing component are very similar to AWT component. They generally prefix the AWT components with a `J`, for instance `JPanel`. See [more about Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- Don't explicitly call `paint()` as you do in your `update()` method. Instead call `repaint()`
- You should call `super.paint(g)` in the `paint` method, if you are not going to paint the background yourself. You will see the leftover paint artifacts if you dont.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a simple tutorial you would recommend about using panels?

Comment: I don't know any tutorials for AWT, but you can check out the Swing Components [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html). For custom painting [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). Like I said, switching from AWT to Swing isn't too difficult. Many times it's just a matter of adding a J in front of your component. See the tutorial. You'll see what I mean